# Efficient pythonic way to compute the difference between the max and min elements of each tuple in a large list of tuples

Tags: python, algorithm

Using the following code, I am trying to calculate the difference between the max and min elements of each tuple in a large list of tuples and store the results in a list. However, the code runs for long time and then OS kills it because it consumes huge amount of RAM. The large list is generated by choosing `n` numbers from a list, basically all possible ways as shown in the snippet below. I think the issue lies exactly there: itertools.combinations, which tries to store a massive list in memory.

I need the sum of the diffs arising from each combination actually, that's why I thought first I would get the diffs in a list and then call sum.

```
import itertools

n = 40

lst = [639, 744, 947, 856, 102, 639, 916, 665, 766, 679, 679, 484, 658, 559, 564, 3, 384, 763, 236, 404, 566, 347, 866, 285, 107, 577, 989, 715, 84, 280, 153, 76, 24, 453, 284, 126, 92, 200, 792, 858, 231, 823, 695, 889, 382, 611, 244, 119, 726, 480]

result = [max(x)-min(x) for x in itertools.combinations(lst, n)]
```

It will be a great learning experience for me if someone provides a hint about tackling this issue.

Comment: Do you need the full list of diffs (i.e. one entry for every possible combination) or is it sufficient just to get the set of distinct possible diffs?

Comment: I need the sum of the diffs arising from each combination actually, that's why I thought first I would get the diffs in a list and then call sum

Comment: `combinations` uses constant memory. You are expiclty trying to build a list with one element per combination, though. Given `n` and `lst`, that's something like 10 billion values.

Comment: @chepner how do I do otherwise, if I need the sum of the diffs arising from each combination?

Comment: @WasimAftab something like this - (a) work out all the possible pairs of max(x) and min(x), (b) for each pair, work out how many different combinations have that max and min. You can do this without producing all the 40-item combinations.

Comment: What is the point of `n`?  You would get *exactly* the same set of max-min differences if you used `n=2`, since only two values out of each combination contribute to that result.

Comment: @jasonharper There are more *of* the combinations, though, which affects the final sum.

Comment: @jasonharper not quite the same I think? Imagine `lst` were in sorted order. Then if n=2, `(lst[0], lst[1])` is a possible pair of min and max, but not if n=40.

Comment: Surely the problem originates from the huge number of combinations. With the question as stated there are 1e10 combinations. With, for example,  1000 numbers and a sample size of 40 then there are 5e71 combinations. Storing such results becomes impractical. The issue does not arise from itertools.combinations which does not create the List 'in advance' Here is a link to a combinations size calculator [here](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/combinations.php)

Comment: All important information needs to be in the question, not just in the comments. That you just want the sum, that's very important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same basic idea as in [slothrop's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75291241/12671057) but implemented differently and much faster. I use an outer loop for how many list numbers shall exist *between* the max and min numbers:

```
def Kelly2(lst, n):
    lst = sorted(lst)
    total = 0
    for between in range(n-2, len(lst)-1):
        combs = comb(between, n-2)
        diffs = sum(b - a for a, b in zip(lst, lst[between+1:]))
        total += combs * diffs
    return total
```

From the `between` numbers, we have to choose `n-2`, since we want n including min and max. This number of combinations is the same for all min/max pairs with `between` numbers between them, so we only compute it once. And instead of multiplying it with every max-min difference, sum those differences and multiply them with the combinations only once.

This can be taken further, as both `combs` and `diffs` change just a little when we increase `between`. Here are benchmark times with "50 choose 45" instead of your original "50 choose 40" (so chepner's brute force is still fast enough) up to "200000 choose 160000":

```
50 choose 45
 5.281 s  chepner
 0.000 s  slothrop_1
 0.000 s  slothrop_2
 0.000 s  Kelly
 0.000 s  Kelly2
 0.000 s  Kelly3
 0.000 s  Kelly4
 0.000 s  Kelly5

2000 choose 1600
 4.292 s  slothrop_1
 0.064 s  slothrop_2
 0.041 s  Kelly
 0.041 s  Kelly2
 0.037 s  Kelly3
 0.034 s  Kelly4
 0.001 s  Kelly5

10000 choose 8000
 5.036 s  slothrop_2
 3.795 s  Kelly
 3.675 s  Kelly2
 3.622 s  Kelly3
 3.533 s  Kelly4
 0.008 s  Kelly5

100000 choose 80000
 0.527 s  Kelly5

200000 choose 160000
 2.130 s  Kelly5
```

Here's that super fast one:

```
def Kelly5(lst, n):
    lst = sorted(lst)
    total = 0
    diffs = sum(lst[n-1:]) - sum(lst[:-n+1])
    combs = 1
    for between in range(n-2, len(lst)-1):
        total += combs * diffs
        combs = combs * (between+1) // (between-n+3)
        diffs += lst[~between-1] - lst[between+1]
    return total
```

`Kelly3` and `Kelly4` are intermediate optimizations from `Kelly2` to `Kelly5`, making it easier to see how I got there.

Full code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVZLb@M2EL7rVwywh0iJlNXTlo3m1EMPRX1oj4FhKDYVM5VIQaSReBfbv56doShL9rp5LFKgRhAN5z3fjMRp9norRZI37fNz2coaNK8Z8LqRrTa0Y2muWaulrJQPdaG3PrSF2MjaMUbE6Y3Wsr5zHAE3kIZOpTQSt5Nk5sM0TX2YpVMf8mziQxTGPhjBLMLjZJKhyoSo6cz@S3O0mGS5D1mGx2yCxwT/iD2dIBUnqJ@GKcmQSoxzouI8owh4zKb4b5ZT/Ah5ZBrnIQqzhJzgCTkpHWKSRTGyZphZHKLSlKicEoiTCKkY1SYzckMOk5wqiCLyQaYRBSH7NA@XjuNsWAnrLWsEa10EwgfhzR3AX8v0rhWgdrVbF0/ukwcB1FwQUcoWnoCLAe9rApSLQnMpVO/Hs@5VJfW2lc0qGkdQHewK28E2JPCQWQiFvBApisF9eHghDDb3nrkVEy758jws0ebOSzT8BfiVCKKOA9hyobnYMXMUK/KEoWgojFf3IeABoiSC2DMqlMrVTa95CSbI7cMSYTAUX5KeRQmVT4uNXynWATOFVO/XZj5KpOmSMAg0VH5XJ/J8OBQbRN4350fABvVBU1xFFhZSeRhUDDwjn14PlS3dpHdrcFn@CwCnCHyCP/YgW36PTaoMHr@zqtofT9a5xh/Nm02jA8i9Y/qRMWFRuTQad5hEYeopfLijkr7wpotCqVmTq2i@9LyDN1K3kjOwWlSNtmdK@ZM9tlxr1H7k@OmopGyUcaK3DKoChxJkg58f/qUbyKHe@C0Fa6mLyjbvjcnNj5Chzv@I0EFlw8uSVH4ary7BfhAQeeNx3CyjYbD6VdbNTjMbtFCGAFlSdAUuF0qzYmMZ9DCK3gBZ8n@D7BQXGnvLnv9jBcuPAOtuD7tmgyMk7o@AMpeWWreFXm9HQKXvB@q0LPoqHhdEHwlbzMej@gI0Q3Yopkx6ZOmTExzP5vJlMDvn7wQz@4/B7NGJfgbaV3AbI09S94CUB58/H46YTeJ9DNjlTqxNxG5f8Ec3@4jGcgy29tEfE/tM7TPD5gUBtq9t2VoLphQEb/45jtrSHtfVMY9xlSFw6wHW/rIkNe9wA7KnBoOhmSnlNlx2CrguDsNfkpNOjp0d2tEytauM7YmRuTKVwh3loHNjI3U1/tUwtnlHdX2Nn@A3hjjjTQMKr5mqaPHaae/x3uECZx5wzgszy/dY6cKWSEvtAschpyGIwtFcd8vw9Xor@Zr161Mcou4Cd6e/bxZHF3H3YnRLjWZK2zfF76CxwZqWC@320@vDBTqXil3QK3UM@EIKdgbi8Yek2ff9XA7vALJow3e9c30gm0OoY3UcaH1gd2mWF1/1fHKdlN9AAaZYXq9WoqjZajU4wM3RpsyVyXlI8KicLolX2z8Ex5ViQDHNehg75iU1EJf50POHyRvLonAsjM8IB2lwYhufET8/fwc)):

```
from time import time
import itertools, math, random
from math import comb

n = 40
lst = [639, 744, 947, 856, 102, 639, 916, 665, 766, 679, 679, 484, 658, 559, 564, 3, 384, 763, 236, 404, 566, 347, 866, 285, 107, 577, 989, 715, 84, 280, 153, 76, 24, 453, 284, 126, 92, 200, 792, 858, 231, 823, 695, 889, 382, 611, 244, 119, 726, 480]


def chepner(lst, n):
    return sum(max(x) - min(x) for x in itertools.combinations(lst, n))


def slothrop_1(lst, n):
  slst = sorted(lst)
  ans = 0
  for i, j in itertools.combinations(range(len(slst)), 2):
    if j < i+n-1:
      continue
    n_comb = math.comb(j-i-1, n-2)
    ans += n_comb * (slst[j] - slst[i])
  return ans


def slothrop_2(lst, n):
  slst = sorted(lst)

  combs = {p: math.comb(p, n-2) for p in range(n-2, len(slst)-1)}

  ans = 0
  for i in range(len(slst)-n+1):
    for j in range(i+n-1, len(slst)):
      ans += combs[j-i-1] * (slst[j] - slst[i])

  return ans


# My original
def Kelly(lst, n):
    lst = sorted(lst)
    return sum(
        comb(between, n-2) * sum(b - a for a, b in zip(lst, lst[between+1:]))
        for between in range(n-2, len(lst)-1)
    )


# Rewritten with loops for the later optimizations
def Kelly2(lst, n):
    lst = sorted(lst)
    total = 0
    for between in range(n-2, len(lst)-1):
        combs = comb(between, n-2)
        diffs = sum(b - a for a, b in zip(lst, lst[between+1:]))
        total += combs * diffs
    return total


# Compute diffs as diff of sums (instead of sum of diffs)
def Kelly3(lst, n):
    lst = sorted(lst)
    total = 0
    for between in range(n-2, len(lst)-1):
        combs = comb(between, n-2)
        diffs = sum(lst[between+1:]) - sum(lst[:~between])
        total += combs * diffs
    return total


# Compute diffs by updating (instead of from scratch)
def Kelly4(lst, n):
    lst = sorted(lst)
    total = 0
    diffs = sum(lst[n-1:]) - sum(lst[:-n+1])
    for between in range(n-2, len(lst)-1):
        combs = comb(between, n-2)
        total += combs * diffs
        diffs += lst[~between-1] - lst[between+1]
    return total


# Compute combs by updating (instead of from scratch)
def Kelly5(lst, n):
    lst = sorted(lst)
    total = 0
    diffs = sum(lst[n-1:]) - sum(lst[:-n+1])
    combs = 1
    for between in range(n-2, len(lst)-1):
        total += combs * diffs
        combs = combs * (between+1) // (between-n+3)
        diffs += lst[~between-1] - lst[between+1]
    return total


funcs = chepner, slothrop_1, slothrop_2, Kelly, Kelly2, Kelly3, Kelly4, Kelly5

#-- Correctness ------------------------------------------

short = lst[:20]
for m in range(2, len(short)+1):
    expect = funcs[0](short, m)
    for f in funcs[1:]:
        result = f(short, m)
        assert result == expect

#-- Speed ------------------------------------------------

# Generate similar larger input data
def gen(N):
    n = N * 8 // 10
    lst = random.choices(range(20 * N), k=N)
    return lst, n

def test(lst, n, funcs):
    print(len(lst), 'choose', n)
    expect = None
    for f in funcs:
        copy = lst[:]
        t = time()
        result = f(copy, n)
        t = time() - t
        print(f'{t:6.3f} s ', f.__name__)
        if expect is None:
            expect = result
        assert result == expect
    print()

test(lst, 45, funcs)
test(*gen(2000), funcs[1:])
test(*gen(10000), funcs[2:])
test(*gen(100000), funcs[-1:])
test(*gen(200000), funcs[-1:])
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed analysis, your 5th snippet is blazingly fast!!

Answer (score 2):

Using the approach outlined in the comments on @chepner's answer.

The print statements in the loop show the code doing what I intend, but I haven't independently verified the overall answer is correct.

```
import itertools
import math

n = 40
lst = [639, 744, 947, 856, 102, 639, 916, 665, 766, 679, 679, 484, 658, 559, 564, 3, 384, 763, 236, 404, 566, 347, 866, 285, 107, 577, 989, 715, 84, 280, 153, 76, 24, 453, 284, 126, 92, 200, 792, 858, 231, 823, 695, 889, 382, 611, 244, 119, 726, 480]
slst = sorted(lst)

ans = 0
for i, j in itertools.combinations(range(len(slst)), 2):
  # i and j are candidate *indexes* into slst (not values):
  # we'll count how many combinations have minimum slst[i] and maximum slst[j]
  
  if j < i+n-1:
    # In this case there can't be an n-item combination
    # whose minimum is slst[i] and maximum is slst[j]:
    # there aren't enough items with values in between
    continue

  # How many n-item combinations have minimum slst[i] and maximum slst[j]?
  # It's the number of ways we can pick the (n-2) other members of the combination
  # from the (j-i-1) values between i and j in slst.
  n_comb = math.comb(j-i-1, n-2)
  print(f"{n_comb} combinations with minimum {slst[i]} (index {i}) and maximum {slst[j]} (index {j})")

  # Each of these combinations contributes slst[j] - slst[i] to the sum:
  ans += n_comb * (slst[j] - slst[i])

print(f"Overall sum of differences: {ans}")
```

Result:

```
[omitted the lines for individual pairs of indices]
Overall sum of differences: 9965200498117
```

Another version with a couple of optimisations (avoiding repeated calls to `math.comb` with the same values, and looping explicitly over just the relevant pairs of `i, j`):

```
import math

n = 40
lst = [639, 744, 947, 856, 102, 639, 916, 665, 766, 679, 679, 484, 658, 559, 564, 3, 384, 763, 236, 404, 566, 347, 866, 285, 107, 577, 989, 715, 84, 280, 153, 76, 24, 453, 284, 126, 92, 200, 792, 858, 231, 823, 695, 889, 382, 611, 244, 119, 726, 480]
slst = sorted(lst)

combs = {p: math.comb(p, n-2) for p in range(n-2, len(slst)-1)}

ans = 0
for i in range(len(slst)-n+1):
  for j in range(i+n-1, len(slst)):
    ans += combs[j-i-1] * (slst[j] - slst[i])

print(f"Overall sum of differences: {ans}")
```

Comment: This is pretty quick for your data, but a couple of optimisations that could still be done: (1) instead of iterating over all pairs of indices and discarding the invalid pairs, write nested loops over explicit ranges for i and j, (2) cache the values of `math.comb` since the same values are used repeatedly.

Comment: In fact, (1) could be taken all the way to replacing the nested loop with a sum over a generator comprehension - much more compact, but probably not so transparent in communicating the logic of hte approach.

Comment: I verified it now. For smaller cases it agrees with chepner's brute force solution, and for larger cases it agrees with my own solution. If you implement your optimizations, I could include that in my benchmark.

Comment: @KellyBundy Cool, see the edit - it still won't beat yours though :)

Comment: Ok, updated my benchmark. It does get close to my solutions except my final one. I had btw tried yours with caching, but I was too lazy to think of something like what you did now, I just did `comb = functools.lru_cache(None)(math.comb)` (not sure I ever used a decorator without decorator syntax before, except when explaining decorator syntax).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sum, you don't need to store them all in memory at once. Just add them as you compute them.

```
s = sum(max(x) - min(x) for x in itertools.combinations(lst, n))
```

It will still take a while to iterate over all the combinations, but this will use a small constant amount of memory.

Comment: thanks, but it is not good enough, I already tried that.

Comment: If you really need all the combinations, there's nothing you can do. This is not a matter of cleverly pruning the search tree to find some small set of combinations from the space of all combinations. You literally want to look at all of them. (Unless you can find a way to *count* the number of combinations that yield a given min/max pair, in which case you can do something like `sum(compute_count(x, y) for x, y in combinations(lst, 2))`, along the lines of jasonharper's comment above. (Where every pair of values from `lst` is potentially a min/max pair of some 40-element combination.)

Comment: thank you but I am not sure how your snippet above helps in computing differences of min max elements in each combination.

Comment: Sketch of a possible solution: first sort `lst`. Then there is 1 combination that has min `lst[0]` and max `lst[39]`. There are 40 (=`math.comb(40, 1)`) combinations that have min `lst[0]` and max `lst[40]`.  There are 780 (=`math.comb(40, 2)`) combinations that have min `lst[0]` and max `lst[41]`... and so on.

Comment: @slothrop okay, but you still need to iterate through the billions of combinations isn't it?

Comment: @WasimAftab no - if you know there are `N` combinations with minimum `x` and maximum `y`, then you know they contribute `N * (y - x)` to your overall sum. There's no need to iterate over all the combinations to calculate that.  You just need to iterate over all possible pairs of endpoints, which is a much smaller number.

Comment: `50 choose 40` is ~10 billion. `50 choose 2` is only ~1200.

Comment: @WasimAftab - I'm slightly off on my math in the earlier comment. There are `math.comb(39, 38)` (=39) combinations with min `lst[0]` and max `lst[40]`. There are `math.comb(40, 38)` (=780) combinations with min `lst[0]` and max `lst[41]`. There are `math.comb(41, 38)` (=10660) combinations with min `lst[0]` and max `lst[42]`...etc. The principle still works - it should be much much quicker than iterating every individual 40-item combination.

Comment: @slothrop I am aiming at iterating every individual 40 elements (a tuple in the large list) only. using your approach eventually you need to iterate through all the combinations right? otherwise, how would you compute the differences? If possible please test it on your machine once

Comment: @WasimAftab sure, see my attempt at an answer